# Cant seem to get the value of inputs while having modal PHP HTML

Tags: php, html

Here is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask"  target="frame">
<input class="date-picker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" type="text" name="fn" id="fn1" onchange="checkInput()">
        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="btn1" disabled class="btn btn-success" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit Order</button></form>
```

This is my script, I didnt put my other inputs here, but in reality i have 4 inputs in sublime..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        function checkInput(){
                          if($("#fn1"). val()!="" && $("#ln1").val()!= "" && $("#cn1").val()!= "" && $("#add1").val()!= ""){
                             $("#btn1").prop("disabled", false);
                             event.preventDefault();
                          }
                          else{
                             $("#btn1").prop("disabled", true);
                          }
                        }
                      </script>
```

This is the submit post:

```
<!-- START OF PHP -->
<?php include ('connectdb.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{    
    $fn = $_POST["fn"];
    $add = $_POST["add"];
    $cn = $_POST["cn"];
    $ln = $_POST["ln"];

    //get cart no
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE cartuser = '$userid' and cartpend='IN CART'";
         $result = $conn->query($sql);
         while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $_SESSION["cartrn"] = $data['cartrn'];
              $cartrn =  $_SESSION["cartrn"];
            }

    $sqldist = "UPDATE cart_rec SET cartpend='PENDING', cartfn='$fn', cartadd='$add', cartland= '$ln', cartcn='$cn' WHERE cartuser='$userid' and cartpend='IN CART'";
             if ($conn->query($sqldist) === TRUE) {

        $sqlwallet="UPDATE accounts SET wallet='$mywallet' WHERE usernamee='$userid'";
             if ($conn->query($sqlwallet) === TRUE) {

           $sqldel="DELETE FROM cart WHERE cartuser='$userid'";
             if ($conn->query($sqldel) === TRUE) {
                  echo "DONE";

              }
              else {
              echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
              }
            }  
          }
  } // SUBMIT
?>
```

My problem is that, when the button is enabled, i cant seem to get the value of the inputs which are fn, cn, ln, and add.. 
FYI: I need the data modal, data-backdrop="static" and target="frame" to be in the form.. 
What happened? really need some help thanks a lot!!

Comment: Advices (not solutions): I don't think you need to write `!=""` or `=== TRUE`.  Prepared statements should be used.

Comment: Do you have a session_start call in your script?

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO. Ones that were solved should be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code.  The first thing is the missing `action` (Unless you are using the same file when submitted. However, it is a good practice to use the `action`).

The second one is because you are using `target="frame"`, the values are passed through `get` not `post`. So, to access values, you will need to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

For an instance, the following lines,

```
$fn = $_POST["fn"];
$add = $_POST["add"];
$cn = $_POST["cn"];
$ln = $_POST["ln"];
```

needs to be ,

```
$fn = $_GET["fn"];
$add = $_GET["add"];
$cn = $_GET["cn"];
$ln = $_GET["ln"];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Angela. I am glad it worked for you. Could you please mark this as the accepted answer then? Thanks.

Comment: Yes will do! :)

Comment: @Angela Consider accepting a right answer with the ✔ next to the preferred answer ;-) . Thanks